# Least positive eigenvalue of a Laplacian matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numeric, eigenvalue

To calculate the eigenvalues of a Laplacian matrix, I used the function `numpy.linalg.eig`. The least positive eigenvalue I obtained was `2.6645352591003757e-15`. What is wrong in the calculation? Is it related to floating point arithmetic?

Comment: how much precision are you expecting?

Comment: I expect that the first value should be exactly 0.(as it was defined in theory)

Comment: Yes it is connected to floating-point arithmetic. Read the [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) paper, from 1991 and still crucial, before you hurt yourself.

Comment: Also study the documentation for [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) carefully. This function helps you decide if a value is close enough to 0 to be 0.

Comment: How large is your Laplacian matrix?